# elastic search query to compare two date fields while fetching

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 date fields `updated_date` and `creation date`. I'm trying to build a query using boolquery or searchbuilder where I need all records where updation_date is greater than creation date

tried with range query but it didn't work

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48951494/4604579 (hint: use a script query or better create a new field with the date diff that you can check using a `range` query)

Answer (score 3):

Use script filter,
Use isAfter() for greater than in painless script.

```
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['update_date'].date.isAfter(doc['created_date'].date)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/5-0-comparing-dates-in-painless/63943 this will help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are aware about head plugin https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head

Use the structured query tab to create the query. Select the check box 'Show query source' to see the generated query script.